# Classic asp page generating 404 error in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, asp-classic

I have an asp.net application running in IIS 7.5. I have a standalone classic asp page that I've migrated from another site that I've now included as part of the asp.net application. I'm hosting the application on my local machine, but whenever I navigate to the classic asp page, I get a 404 Not Found error. The page is not missing and I have turned on ASP in IIS through Windows features. The asp.net pages are working fine.

Curiously, I have been able to host the page as its own site in IIS, but not when it's integrated with asp.net.

The IIS logfile contains the following line for the request:

```
2013-11-06 16:25:33 127.0.0.1 GET /test/testpage.asp - 80 [username] 127.0.0.1 [system info] 404 0 2 120
```

Thanks for any and all suggestions, let me know if you need any more information.

**Edit 1**

I got Failed Request Tracing working and was able to find this error in the logfiles when I traced the `MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS` event:

```
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification 16 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)
```

Comment: What is the sub-status of the failed request? This is the number just to the right of the 404 in the logs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited my post with that info - the codes at the end were `404 0 2 120`

Comment: The '0' is the worst possible status because it doesn't tell us anything. Next steps I would try: Renaming the file from testpage.asp to testpage.html, does that work? Enable 'Failed Request Tracing' (which you may have to install first). The fact that classic asp works on a different site on the same server points to a problem with the configuration of the site/application pool. Compare the configuration of the sites/pools involved.

Comment: Changing the extension had no effect and I had some trouble setting up Failed Request Tracing so I checked the app pool settings. Oddly, the site with the standalone asp page and the site with the integrated page are in the same app pool (with the same settings), but the standalone site works and the integrated one doesn't, as before. Will do some more investigating and hopefully get Failed Request Tracing working.

Comment: Curiously, if I go into IIS content view and right-click the page I'm trying to access and select "Browse", I am able to see the page.

Comment: Seems like this could be an HttpHandler problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution to this problem was super embarrassing - the link to the page was wrong, which was why it was working in every other capacity. At least I learned a lot about IIS?